# Core Data delete object on reassignment

Tags: core-data

In Core Data, is it possible for have objects automatically deleted on reassignment?

For example if I have

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged public var name: String?
  @NSManaged public var group: Group?
}

class Group: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged public var people: Set<Person>?
}
```

and assign a new set to a group's `people` property:

```
group.people = [some new set of <Person>]`
```

and then save the current context. I would like all the previous `Person` objects in the previous set to be deleted.
Do I have to to call delete on them manually before the new assignment or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, it turns out that the *Cascade* Delete Rule does not delete a Group's Persons unless you delete the Group.  So I've gutted my answer and replaced with this.

If you don't want to delete the Group, you must delete each Person *and* remove it from the relationship.  It is not that bad, though…

```
if let people = group.people {
    for person in people {
        if let person = person as? NSManagedObject {
            managedObjectContext.delete(person)
        }
    }
}
group.mutableSetValue(forKey: "people").removeAllObjects()
```

NSBatchDeleteRequest might also work if you configured it with a predicate to filter only Persons in the relevant group, but unless you have thousands of Persons to delete I would not bother with it.

Comment: Thanks Jerry! I set up a sample project here: https://github.com/nambatee/CoreDataDeleteOnReassignment. I start out with 1 group with 7 people and then attempt to assign a different set to that group's `people` set (https://github.com/nambatee/CoreDataDeleteOnReassignment/blob/master/CoreDataDeleteOnReassignment/ModelController.swift#L48). The objects from the old set stick around but their `group` becomes nil. I set the delete rule to `Cascade` as you recommended. Did I miss something? I'm running the project, tap on the "Replace" button and break on the assertion in `ViewController`.

Comment: Well, after trying your demo, and working with a simpler one of my own, I'm convinced that the *Cascade* Delete Rule does not does not delete objects from the store upon removing them from their relationship.  I even tried to use the mutable set accessor… `group.mutableSetValue(forKey:"people").removeAllObjects()`, and called `.processPendingChanges` on the managed object context, but still the orphaned students remained in the store and in the managed object context.